# He tenido problemas para eliminar nodos repetidos c++

Tags: c++

Llevo aproximadamente 3 días ya y no he podido ver una solución por mi mismo, ya me pasaron una solución, pero en ningún caso esta borra los nodos duplicados más bien se los salta, he intentado de todo y esta es una de las tantas formas de las cuales usé, si alguien pudiera explicarme se lo agradecería.

Adjunto el código:

```
void nuevaListaSinDuplicados(Nodo *&Nlista)
{
    if(Nlista!=NULL){
        Nodo *aux=Nlista;
        Nodo *duplicado;
        int fec,codigo,camas;
        while(aux!=NULL){
            fec=Nlista->fecha;
            codigo=Nlista->codigo_hospital;
            camas=Nlista->numero_de_cama;
            if((aux->fecha==fec) && (aux->codigo_hospital==codigo) && (aux->numero_de_cama==camas)){
                duplicado=Nlista;
                Nlista=Nlista->sgte;
                aux=aux->sgte;
                delete duplicado;
            }
            else{
                if((aux->sgte!=NULL) && (aux->sgte->fecha==fec) && (aux->sgte->codigo_hospital==codigo) && (aux->sgte->numero_de_cama==camas)){
                    duplicado=aux->sgte;
                    aux->sgte=aux->sgte->sgte;
                    delete duplicado;
                }
                else{
                    aux=aux->sgte;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tomas el primero, recorres toda la lista borrando los duplicados, tomas el segundo, y sigues. Donde es que tienes tu problema especificamente. Ademas, estas en C++, porque no usar `std::list` y `std::remove`?

Comment: Estoy aprendiendo a programar y aún no veo esas funciones, pero por la misma razón me cree la cuenta, quiero mejorar y poder entender mis errores. muchas gracias por responder. el problema del codigo es que no funciona porque hay 4000+ nodos y solo me elimina uno :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Por lo que veo estás trabajando con una lista enlazada simple, de ser así no estás eliminando los nodos bien:

```
if((aux->fecha==fec) && (aux->codigo_hospital==codigo) && (aux->numero_de_cama==camas)){
    duplicado=Nlista;
    Nlista=Nlista->sgte;
    aux=aux->sgte;
    delete duplicado;
}
```

Suponiendo una lista como esta:

[image]

Las operaciones que haces dejan la lista así:

[image]

1. Los punteros `aux` y `Nlista` apuntan al mismo nodo, así que **siempre** van a detectar un duplicado.
2. No re-enlazas los nodos, necesitas guardar el nodo **anterior** para hacer que éste apunte al nodo **siguiente** al que estás eliminando.

Cuando se borran nodos en una lista simple, el caso de borrar el primer nodo es especial (pues no tiene nodo anterior) sin embargo, como estás buscando duplicados este caso no se dará nunca, así que el código será más sencillo:

```
void nuevaListaSinDuplicados(Nodo *&Nlista)
{
    for (Nodo *nodo = Nlista; nodo; nodo = nodo->sgte)
    {
        const int fec = nodo->fecha;
        const int codigo = nodo->codigo_hospital;
        const int camas = nodo->numero_de_cama;

        for (Nodo *anterior = nodo, *actual = nodo->sgte; actual;)
        {
            if ((fec == actual->fecha) &&
                (codigo == actual->codigo_hospital) &&
                (camas == actual->numero_de_cama))
            {
                anterior->sgte = actual->sgte;
                delete actual;
                actual = anterior->sgte;
            }
            else
            {
                anterior = actual;
                actual = actual->sgte;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vZPLbsIwEEXX9leMVKmBCqQ@dgRYdVmx6bYSch2DLBk78oMuUL49HdsJhFeXjUSwZ67P9YwdXtdTrpjetu2D1FyFSsBcGuetYLslpTgI3MPKVIYeKJHaQ8W8KSmJIXhyWy9gATooVXtb0qakdG9kBd/GWrYWes2Z46xio6x/1Pg3TqgNjPKEkCtxTEyXET5Gq0oogTYxiA6dgQ5izz6k8@xT6vdQK4krjet9ViqmktPGWOjCEYHbzckyE6ELDjwpwWWEG@089CUfFV39QyzTXliJ86yZYIT7wNQZtYQcLGPFkZ9akNGLLpfpUZAVpCdnBJx0iZgkXXc6eF7Vu58vT8kmvoRy4trkiL@kXHpGBv6aeBixPzsm9Sj1@tRmF4sXP@nqHF4mt8evg/HbPU2THrxYueUsYMcGZ@b@OkfifDWbcRM8zOddKh8nTgsosJwzRfGli@h073Ylw/H/7uXm15E3YYUPVsMzfhZt@ws)</kbd>.

Comment: Entendí perfecto, muchas gracias por la ayuda :) Pd:Tengo una duda respecto el porque usas el "const int".

Comment: Ese `const` hace que el compilador se queje si intentas modificar la variable. Es una guarda que suele evitar que metas la pata y modifiques sin querer una variable que no debería ser modificada

Comment: Uh perfecto, lo empezaré a utilizar en ciertas situaciones entonces, gracias denuevo!

Comment: @Dvrko lee el [tour] y recorda votar y aceptar las respuestas que te sirvieron.. esa es la forma de decir gracias en este sitio!

Answer (score 2):

Un error que tienes es que estás asumiendo que el siguiente `if`:

```
if((aux->fecha==fec) && (aux->codigo_hospital==codigo) && (aux->numero_de_cama==camas)){
    duplicado=Nlista;
    Nlista=Nlista->sgte;
    aux=aux->sgte;
    delete duplicado;
}
```

solo va a entrar en acción cuando el nodo a borrar sea el primero. ¿De dónde viene esa asunción? Si no es el primer nodo, `aux` y `NLista` apuntan a nodos distintos ... ¿De verdad quieres borrar el primer nodo? Yo creo que no.

Por resumir un poco:

- Necesitas un puntero para saber qué nodo coges como referencia
- Necesitas un puntero para recorrer la lista, partiendo del siguiente nodo al de referencia
- Necesitas un puntero al nodo inmediatamente anterior al que recorre la lista: para poder borrar el siguiente nodo

Organizando el algoritmo de borrado, yo lo dejaría así:

```
Nodo * referencia = NLista;

while (referencia->sgte != nullptr)
{
    Nodo * anterior = referencia;
    Nodo * actual = referencia->sgte;
  
    while (actual != nullptr)
    {
        if (condiciónes del nodo a borrar)
        {
            anterior->sgte = actual->sgte;
            delete actual;
            actual = anterior->sgte;
        }
        else
        {
            anterior = actual;
            actual = actual->sgte;
        }
    }
    referencia=referencia->sgte;
}
```

Ahora tenemos dos bucles: Uno que mueve el nodo de referencia y otro que busca duplicados de ese nodo en adelante. El primer nodo nunca lo vamos a tocar, ya que ese será el primer nodo de referencia, luego nunca puede ser tomado como un nodo duplicado.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda me quedo perfectamente claro :)